# Dynamic text using UiBinder

Tags: gwt, uibinder

I need to prepare UiBinder template for the following (simplified) case:

```html
<div class="recipient">
    <strong>Recipient: </strong> Will Smith
</div>
```

Of course first and last name are dynamic.

I ended up with this in UiBinder xml:

```xml
<g:HTMLPanel addStyleNames="recipient">
    <strong>Recipient: </strong> <span ui:field='recipient'/>
</g:HTMLPanel>
```

As you see produced html will have additional `span` element. I want to achieve exactly the same html.  Is there are any (simple) way / UI component to do it? Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT.** I do not want to extract `<strong>Recipient: </strong>` from UiBinder (we can imagine a case with a lot more html markup before and after dynamic text, and it looks natural to me that it must be a part of (some) UiBinder template)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You won't have other choices but to emit the whole `<strong>Recipent: </strong> Will Smith` string, and for that, `SafeHtmlTemplates` can help (or `Messages` if you want internationalization at the expense of HTML *safety*).

Let's use an `HTML` widget for your `<div class="recipient">` (if you can, use a simple `<div>` though):

```
<g:HTML styleName="recipient" ui:field="recipient" />
```

and then in your Java code:

```
interface Templates extends SafeHtmlTemplates {
  @Template("<strong>Recipient: </strong> {0}")
  SafeHtml recipient(String recipient);
}

static final Templates TEMPLATES = GWT.create(Templates.class);
```

(use a `SafeHtml` as argument if you have HTML rather than text)

```
recipient.setHTML(TEMPLATES.recipent("Will Smith"));
```

---

That being said, let me question your initial goal: why do you want to remove the `span`?

Comment: Thank you for you response Thomas. You answered initial question. The problem is that I missed one important for me part: I want to live all html markup before dynamic part in UiBinder file (because for me UiBinder file is a right place for all markup). I am almost sure that it is impossible to do. Looks like everithing between HTMLPanel tags treated like plain string by UiBinder. I accept your answer later to be sure that I do not missed any other possibility. Thank you again for SafeHtmlTemplate way.

Comment: I want to remove `span` because: 1) html/css is prepared before GWT markup 2) I cannot change html/css. I am trying to change process: prepare css for GWT screens, but I am not there yet. So I must find all ways to solve problems from GWT side at this moment.